# Is it possible that posting with `requests` and `MultipartEncoder` results in bad transfer or partial upload?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-toolbelt

When trying to upload a file using `request.post` and `MultipartEncoder`, is it possible that the upload is bad and results in inconsistency between the original file and the received file? Do I need to do any integrity or validity check?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is usually used over TCP:

> An HTTP client initiates a request by establishing a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) connection
> [HTTP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

only some specific versions use UDP (see Wikipedia Article).
TCP itself uses checksum fields to ensure correct transmission:

> To assure correctness a checksum field is included
> [TCP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Error_detection)

So sending the file over HTTP results in a proper transmission and prevents inconsistencies between the original and the received file.

The Library you use should not have an impact on that. So if you use a standard library (as you do) it won’t.

Comment: Aye, if he's having issues he needs to look at encoding and decoding at each end.